# Showing that the estimator of the log posterior used in stochastic gradient MCMC is unbiased

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, estimators, unbiased-estimator

In [the SGLD paper](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Eteh/research/compstats/WelTeh2011a.pdf) as well as in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04696.pdf) it is claimed (paraphrasing) that
the following estimator:

$$\widetilde{U}(\theta) = -\dfrac{|\mathcal{S}|}{|\widetilde{\mathcal{S}}|} \sum_{{x}\in \widetilde{\mathcal{S}}} \log p({x}|\theta) - \log p(\theta); \quad \widetilde{\mathcal{S}} \subset \mathcal{S}. $$

where $\widetilde{\mathcal{S}}$ is a random sample of the dataset $\mathcal{S}$, is an unbiased estimator of $$
U(\theta) = - \sum_{x\in \mathcal{S}} \log p(x|\theta) - \log p(\theta).
$$
How can I show that the estimator $\widetilde{U}(\theta)$ is unbiased?

And as a follow up what if we instead use this estimator (no scaling by $\dfrac{|\mathcal{S}|}{|\widetilde{\mathcal{S}}|}$):
$$\widetilde{U}(\theta) = - \sum_{{x}\in \widetilde{\mathcal{S}}} \log p({x}|\theta) - \log p(\theta); \quad \widetilde{\mathcal{S}} \subset \mathcal{S}. $$
Is this estimator biased? And how does the variance compare to the original?

Comment: Simply take the expectation of $\widetilde{U}(\theta)$  to recover $U(\theta)$ [when $|\widetilde S|$ is non-random]